# How to perform auto Scroll to element in Protractor test if Protractor fails to locate the element int the view?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, end-to-end

I have a suite of tests and would like to auto scroll to elements on the page if protractor fails to locate the element in the current view.

The tests have been written prior to a few changes made to the UI to make the headers fixed. This caused few of the e2e tests to fail.

Currently, I have to go to each of the failing 'it blocks' and perform a scroll to the element using helper functions.

I wish to instruct protractor to look for the element again if it fails to locate the element.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wait(ExpectedCondition), example to wait for the element with some timeout before clicking it or do any other action.

> await waitUntilPresenceOfElement(element(by.id('some id')));

```
export async function waitUntilPresenceOfElement(element: ElementFinder, timeout: number = 5000): Promise<any> {
    return await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(element),
        timeout,
        'Waiting for element ' + element.locator() + 'to be PRSENCE with timeout ' + timeout + 'ms'
    ); }
```

If the element is not found defined by timeout, you have a problem.

Second solution is to work with exception handle and create some retry function.

```
export async function clearText(textBox: ElementFinder) {

    try {
        await textBox.clear().then(() => {
            console.log('Text field has been cleared.');
        });
    } catch (error) {
        // example for no such element exception
        if (error instanceof NoSuchElementError) {
            // retry function
        } else {
            console.log('Error wile trying to clear text from element.');
            throw error;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue where needed to 'scroll' to an element and click which was out of view.

This uses the element and then shifts the view to it so you can click on it:

await browser.actions().mouseMove('element').perform()